# Golang pointer definition

Tags: pointers, go

Guys I have Student struct and I am trying to create Student item as *Student. I get **invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference** error.

```
var newStudent *Student
newStudent.Name = "John"
```

I m creating like that. When I try to set any variable, I am getting same error. What did I wrong?

Comment: It seems that the memory to hold a `Student` is not allocated. Try `var newStudent *Student := new(Student)`

Comment: it s work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for the `Student` `struct`. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Student struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    var newStudent *Student

    newStudent = new(Student)
    newStudent.Name = "John"
    fmt.Println(*newStudent)

    newStudent = &Student{}
    newStudent.Name = "Jane"
    fmt.Println(*newStudent)

    newStudent = &Student{Name: "Jill"}
    fmt.Println(*newStudent)
}
```

Output:

```
{John}
{Jane}
{Jill}
```